# Customising the cookie expiration of Google Analytics... but with 2 trackers

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I would like to customise the cookie duration of Google Analytics, but my tracking uses 2 UA. Not just one.

My current tracking is :

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga("create", "UA-XXXXXX-1", {'cookieDomain': 'auto','cookieExpires': '33696000' });
  ga("create", "UA-XXXXXX-6", 'auto', 'myTracker');

  ga("set", "anonymizeIp", true);
  ga("send", "pageview");
  ga('myTracker.send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I want however to customise the tracking on the second UA as well, but :

`ga("create", "UA-XXXXXXX-6", {'cookieDomain': 'auto','cookieExpires': '33696000' }, 'myTracker');`

Do not seem to work.
Any ideas?

Thanks !

Comment: Unless you rename the cookie for the second tracker both trackers will use the same cookie in any case, so I don't think customizing lifetime for both is necessary.

Comment: That's a fair answer. But then, let me rephrase it. The code given above in my question, do not customize the duration of the "_ga" cookie. Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: Try the following instead: ga("create", "UA-XXXXXX-6", {'cookieDomain': 'auto','name': 'myTracker','cookieExpires': '33696000' });

Comment: Thanks a lot @BronwynV, it does seem to work !

Both hits are being sent, they seem to be using the same cookie, which has therefore the same expiring date.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the previous answers, it's solved, thanks !